# Still can't remove too large file php_errors.log from github repo

Tags: git, github

For 2 days I've been trying to resolve a situation where I can't push an update to github due to the too-large-file thing (php_errors.log is 117.71 MB).

I don't know why github accepted it ever in the first place.

I finally got so desperate I decided to destroy my github repo and create a new empty repo from scratch, this time using their suggested .gitignore file.

At some point I had to restore my entire Linode server.

Now I still cannot push, get

`remote: error: File php_errors.log is 117.71 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB`

I imagine this must be because when I restored my server, all the .git cached stuff returned.

I have followed two SO threads to resolve but with no luck.  Sometimes the suggestions are obsolete.

I have nothing on github and really nothing to lose.  How best to take my Wordpress (recovered from a Linode server restoration) and push it to github, ideally without any logs, cache, etc.  ??

Comment: I doubt that you were able to push that file into github ever. Are you completely sure it's up in github?

Comment: Anyway, the best thing you can do is **rewrite history** to get rid of the offending file in the branch history. Is your branch history a straight line (as in, it has no merge commits)?

Comment: Just now seeing this as SO did not email me.

At one point from github.com it wouldn't let me view the file.

In any case, I have removed the file locally, then did 'touch php_errors.log'.

The only thing in my new repo (again I destroyed the last repo) is .gitignore.

So I really just want to get the new repo pushed to github.com, without all the cache, the logs, all the unnecessary garbage.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to get a new repo I can deal with.

1. I created a brand new git repo on github.
2. I used the Wordpress .gitignore template
3. The gitignore apparently only commits wp-content, but I think that's fine.  In the past I had just committed everything because that seemed safest, but as long as I don't lose my assets and such, this will do.